# after execute dispatch_semaphore_wait(sem, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER) never receive callback

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to wait until my rest service call back receive, but after

```
dispatch_semaphore_wait(sem, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
```

line, everythings stop and i never receive call back. My code is below.

```
__block NSString *strTaggedText=@"";

dispatch_semaphore_t    sem;

sem = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

[[manager2 dataTaskWithRequest:req completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * _Nonnull response, id  _Nullable responseObject, NSError * _Nullable error) {

    if (!error) {
        NSLog(@"Reply JSON: %@", responseObject);
        dictionary=[responseObject objectForKey:@"****"];
        strTaggedText=[dictionary objectForKey:@"Text"];
        NSLog(@"strText = %@",strTaggedText);


    } else
    {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@, %@, %@", error, response, responseObject);


    }
    dispatch_semaphore_signal(sem);

}] resume];

dispatch_semaphore_wait(sem, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);


return strTaggedText;
```

Comment: Just a different approach without using semaphore, change you method with callback  yourMethodWithCallbackHandler:^(NSString * strTaggedText){ } of string argument and call on API response complete. do not user return value.:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've stopped the main runloop, which means no events are getting processed and the app will stop responding.

You are calling an asynchronous method and the main thread is expected to return immediately, after perhaps showing a busy indicator.

Processing is meant to continue from within the block, which will be called in a background thread.  You can then push the data to whereever it's expected to go and cancel the busy indicator. The *next thing* can then be triggered, perhaps on the main thread, but that's up to you; certainly any UI-interaction must be done on the main thread only.

This is [asynchronous programming](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html), but a full discussion is beyond the scope of a stackoverflow answer, in my opinion.

Comment: Okay, it makes sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that this isn't working at all is that you wrote

```
dispatch_semaphore_wait(sem, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
```

on the main thread, and the main thread stops right there until a _signal comes - which won't arrive because your manager2 will *never* reach the code where it resumes the data task.